# google cloud messaging receiver error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When I send a message to my app, I get this message:

```
    08-12 22:17:12.932: W/GTalkService(475): [DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.example.databasetest (has extras) }
    08-12 22:17:12.932: W/GTalkService(475): Receiver package not found, unregister application com.example.databasetest sender
```

It seems that the message must be sending OK if my app picks up on it trying to receive something. This is my manifest with any sensitive values omitted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.databasetest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <permission
          android:name="com.example.databasetest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.databasetest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <permission
          android:name="com.example.databasetest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.databasetest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="value"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.databasetest.GCMreceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.anroid.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
             <action android:name="com.google.anroid.c2dm.permission.REGISTRATION"/>
             <category android:name="com.example.databasetest"/> 

          </intent-filter>  

        </receiver>


    </application>

    </manifest>
```

And this is the receive method in my file, GCMreceiver.java, which seems to be in the right place. The log is never called.

```
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  //receives messages from server
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d("IM", "receive : "+action);
            if(action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"))  //get unique registration id back from server
            {
                String registrationId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
                String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
                Log.d("IM", "registered: " + registrationId);
                if(error != null && !error.isEmpty())
                {
                    Log.d("IM", "error: " + error);
                }

        }
        else if(action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) //or receive message from server
        {
            Log.d("IM", "im receiving");
            if((connector != null) && (connector.loc != null) ) //make sure a gps location is available
            {

                String name = intent.getStringExtra("username");
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                double lati = intent.getExtras().getDouble("latitude");
                double longi = intent.getExtras().getDouble("longitude");
                messages.add(new Message(name, message, lati, longi));
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This looks exactly like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196863/broadcast-intent-cancelled-android-gcm).

Comment: I had already tried that solution. Found the issue, my manifest says permission where it should say intent within the receiver. Now I've just got an issue where everytime the onReceive method tries to access a variable outside of it, it thinks it's null.